# Symfony2 input require

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create a form that have some optional fields (leave them blank), to do this i've added the required => false option to the formbuilder...

```
$builder->add('twitter', 'url', array('required' => 'false'));
```

The Entity doesn't have any Validation Constraints...

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="twitter", type="string", length=50)
 */
private $twitter;
```

Also tried to clear the cache in dev, prod with debug true/false. But the form still have the required attribute when it loads :$

```
<input type="url" id="post_add_twitter" name="post_add[twitter]" required="required" />
```

My setup passes the **php app/check.php**

What i'm doing wrong ?

EDITED: Symfony version 2.1.7, PHP version 5.4.7

Comment: Symfony 2.4.7? I think 2.2 is not out yet. Your php version does not make sense either.

Comment: Ops, my mistake... Completely mixed the numbers :$ Edited and ty for reporting. (Autonote: Go sleep...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'required' attribute takes a boolean, not a string:

```
$builder->add('twitter', 'url', array('required' => false));
```

I haven't looked too deep, but I would imagine that this attribute is type-cast at some point, meaning any string (other than '') will evaluate to true, and force your field into being required

Comment: You're right. I was passing the string 'false' and not a boolean value. ¬¬ I'm Too dumb tonight... Haha MatW ty for helping ;)